# How to create lognormal numbers between a and b in scipy1.0?

Tags: python, scipy

I am using a computer with scipy version 1.0 and can not update the module. I need to create N lognormal points between a and b, How to create the random numbers?

## For scipy 1.4

```
from scipy import stats
x = stats.loguniform.rvs(1,10,size=100,random_state=100)
```

## How to do in scipy1.0

Scipy 1.0 does not have stats.lognormal it only has stats.lognorm with shape parameter.

Any methods using numpy or random modules with also be welcome it need not be only using scipy.

Comment: What about using numpy.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution `scipy.stats.loguniform` is just the new name of `scipy.stats.reciprocal`, and `reciprocal` is available in SciPy 1.0.  So if `loguniform` is what you need, you can use `reciprocal` instead.

Note, however, that the log-uniform distribution is not the same as the log-normal distribution, so it is a bit confusing that the question asked for `lognormal` random variates, but suggests `loguniform` is an acceptable distribution.  It sounds like what you really want is a truncated log-normal distribution.

Comment: Yup, I was confused with log-uniform with log-normal. I was looking for log-normal and instead of using mu and sigma, I needed to control the rvs between two values.